# Cортировка ArrayList<HashMap<integer, integer>>, исправьте ошибку. Java

Tags: java-8

прошу исправить пару ошибок в коде, как я понимаю в основном связанных с сортировкой `ArrayList<HashMap<integer, integer>>`
Код сделал на С# переделываю на Java.
код программы

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

// выдает 3 ошибки компиляцииException in thread "main" 
//java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal load factor: 0.0
//at java.base/java.util.HashMap.<init>(HashMap.java:449)
//at MyEx.solvePuzzle(Main.java:246)
//at Main.main(Main.java:17)

public class Main
{
 public static void main(String args[]) 
    {
        MyEx mEx = new MyEx();
        ArrayList<Integer> clues = new ArrayList<Integer> (Arrays.asList( 0, 0, 0, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 6, 3, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 0, 3, 0, 0 ));
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> rez = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        rez.addAll(mEx.solvePuzzle(clues));
        for(ArrayList<Integer> e : rez)
        {
            for(int e1 : e)
            {
                 System.out.print(e1);
                 System.out.print(',');
            }
        }
    }

}
 class MyEx 
{
        int N = 6;
        int SIDES = 4;
        private  int MASK = (1 << N) - 1;
        int[] possible = new int[N * N];
        int[] s = new int [SIDES * N];
        int[] e = new int[SIDES * N]; 
        int[] inc = new int[SIDES*N];
        int[][] results = new int [N][N];

        ArrayList<Integer> my_clues;
        ArrayList<Integer> order = new ArrayList<Integer>() ;


   void set_value(int x, int v)
   {
       int m = MASK ^ (1 << v);
       int s_row = x - x % N;
       int s_col = x % N;
       for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
       {
           possible[s_row + i] &= m;
           possible[s_col + i * N] &= m;
       }
       possible[x] = 1 << v;
   }
   int check_unique()
   {
       int n_decides = 0;
       for (int i = 0; i < SIDES / 2 * N; i++)
       {

           Map<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> possible_indices = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
           for (int j = s[i], k = 0; k < N; j += inc[i], k++)
           {
               for (int l = 0; l < N; l++)
                   if (((1 << l) & possible[j])!= 0) 
                   {
                       if (!possible_indices.containsKey(l))
                       {
                           possible_indices.put(l, new ArrayList<Integer>());
                       }

                       possible_indices.get(l).add(j); 
                   }
           }
           for (Map.Entry<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> iter : possible_indices.entrySet() )
           {
              int val = iter.getKey();

               if (iter.getValue().size()==1)
               {
                   ArrayList<Integer> values = iter.getValue();
                   int idx = values.get(0);
                   //  int idx = iter.Value[0]; //Было iter.Value[0];

                   if (possible[idx] != (1 << val))
                   {
                       n_decides++;
                       set_value(idx, val);
                   }
               }
           }

       }
       return n_decides;
   }
   public int count_possible(int val)
   {
       int n = 0;
       while (val != 0) //TODO:
       {
           n += val & 1;
           val >>= 1;
       }
       return n;
   }
   public boolean valid()
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < SIDES * N; i++)
       {
           if (my_clues.get(i) == 0) continue;

           boolean is_decided = true;
           for (int j = s[i], k = 0; k < N; j += inc[i], k++)
           {
               if (count_possible(possible[j]) != 1)
               {
                   is_decided = false;
                   break;
               }
           }

           if (is_decided)
           {
               int largest = 0, n_clue = 0;
               for (int j = s[i], k = 0; k < N; j += inc[i], k++)
               {
                   if (largest < possible[j])
                   {
                       n_clue++;
                       largest = possible[j];
                   }
               }
               if (n_clue != my_clues.get(i)) return false;
           }
       }

       return true;
   }
   public void write_results()
   {
       for (int i = 0; i < N * N; i++)
       {
           int x = i / N, y = i % N;
           for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
           {
               if ((1 << j) == possible[i])
               {
                   results[x][y] = j + 1;
                   break;
               }
           }
       }
   }
   public boolean dfs(int idx)
   {
        if (idx >= order.size()) 
       {
           if (valid())
           {
               write_results();
               return true;
           }
           return false;
       }

       int i = order.get(idx);
       int[] possible_bak = new int[N * N];

       System.arraycopy(possible,0, possible_bak,0, N * N);

       for (int j = 0; j < N; j++)
       {
           int m = (1 << j) & possible[i];
           if (m == 0) continue;

           set_value(i, j);
           boolean found = false;
           if (valid())
           {
               found = dfs(idx + 1);
           }
           if (found)
           {
               return true;
           }
           System.arraycopy(possible_bak,0, possible,0,  N * N); 

       }
       return false;
   }
   public ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> solvePuzzle(ArrayList<Integer> clues)
   {
       my_clues = clues;
       for (int i = 0; i < N * N; i++) possible[i] = MASK;

       for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
       {
           s[i] = i;
           e[i] = (N - 1) * N + i;
           inc[i] = N;
       }

       for (int i = 0, j = N; i < N; i++, j++)
       {
           s[j] = i * N + N - 1;
           e[j] = i * N;
           inc[j] = -1;
       }

       for (int i = 0, j = 2 * N; i < N; i++, j++)
       {
           s[j] = N * N - 1 - i;
           e[j] = N - 1 - i;
           inc[j] = -N;
       }

       for (int i = 0, j = 3 * N; i < N; i++, j++)
       {
           s[j] = (N - i - 1) * N;
           e[j] = (N - i) * N - 1;
           inc[j] = 1;
       }

       for (int i = 0; i < SIDES * N; i++)
       {
           if (my_clues.get(i) == 0) continue;
           for (int j = s[i], k = 0; k < N; j += inc[i], k++)
           {
               int m = MASK;
               for (int l = N + k - my_clues.get(i) + 1; l < N; l++) m ^= 1 << l;
               possible[j] &= m;
           }
       }

       while (check_unique() > 0) ;

       ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> idx_npos = new ArrayList<>();;
       for (int i = 0; i < N * N; i++)
       {
           int n_possible = count_possible(possible[i]);
           if (n_possible > 1)
           {
               idx_npos.add((Entry<Integer, Integer>) new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(n_possible, i));
           }
       }
           // вот тут ошибка       
       idx_npos.sort(Map.Entry.<Integer,Integer>comparingByKey().thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()));



    /* На C# это выглядит вот так:
  idx_npos.Sort((a, b) =>
       {
           int comp = a.Key.CompareTo(b.Key);
           return comp != 0 ? comp : (a.Value.CompareTo(b.Value));
       });*/

       order.clear();
       for (int i = 0; i < idx_npos.size(); i++)
       {
           order.add(idx_npos.get(i).getValue());
       }
       dfs(0);

       ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> r = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();   
       for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
       {
           ArrayList<Integer> vec = new ArrayList<Integer>();
           {
               for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) 
               {
                   vec.add(results[i][j]);
               }
               r.add(vec);
           }

       }
       return r;
   }
}
```

Comment: вряд ли вам помогут с этим вопросом...сюда приходят за ответами, которые могут помочь в будущем не только вам

Comment: по сути, у меня проблема с сортировкой, из за этого ошибка компиляции, на C# это выглядит так,  
  /*    idx_npos.Sort((a, b) =>
       {
           int comp = a.Key.CompareTo(b.Key);
           return comp != 0 ? comp : (a.Value.CompareTo(b.Value));
       });*/  на Java я переписал вот так, но код выдает ошибки:  idx_npos.sort(Map.Entry.<Integer,Integer>comparingByKey().thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()));

Comment: Ваш вопрос удалось решить?

Answer (score 0):

В указанном месте ошибки нет и это проверяется указанным ниже тестом, который вы могли написать самостоятельно:

```
import java.util.AbstractMap;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> idx_npos = new ArrayList<>();
        idx_npos.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(1, 1));
        idx_npos.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(4, 1));
        idx_npos.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(2, 1));
        idx_npos.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(3, 4));
        idx_npos.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(2, 2));
        idx_npos.add(new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(3, 1));
        idx_npos.sort(Map.Entry.<Integer,Integer>comparingByKey().thenComparing(Map.Entry.comparingByValue()));
        idx_npos.forEach(integerIntegerEntry -> System.out.println(integerIntegerEntry.getKey() + ":" + integerIntegerEntry.getValue()));
        assert idx_npos.get(0).getKey().equals(1) && idx_npos.get(0).getValue().equals(1);
        assert idx_npos.get(1).getKey().equals(2) && idx_npos.get(1).getValue().equals(1);
        assert idx_npos.get(2).getKey().equals(2) && idx_npos.get(2).getValue().equals(2);
        assert idx_npos.get(3).getKey().equals(3) && idx_npos.get(3).getValue().equals(1);
        assert idx_npos.get(4).getKey().equals(3) && idx_npos.get(4).getValue().equals(4);
        assert idx_npos.get(5).getKey().equals(4) && idx_npos.get(5).getValue().equals(1);
    }
}
```

А вот чуть выше ошибка есть...

```
idx_npos.add((Entry<Integer, Integer>) new HashMap<Integer, Integer>(n_possible, i));
```

Она заключается в не верном истолковании конструктора HashMap. На самом деле вы вызвали конструктор HashMap, со следующим описанием

```
/**
 * Constructs an empty <tt>HashMap</tt> with the specified initial
 * capacity and load factor.
 *
 * @param  initialCapacity the initial capacity
 * @param  loadFactor      the load factor
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the initial capacity is negative
 *         or the load factor is nonpositive
 */
public HashMap(int initialCapacity, float loadFactor)
....
```